# Convert a Bitmap into a resource id

Tags: android

I have a `Bitmap`, and I'd like a resource id (like `R.drawable.whatever`) for it instead to pass to Notification (I'm stuck at api level 8 for compatibility reasons). Is this possible? I suspect not, but I want to make sure before I give up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Sorry :P

Answer (score 1):

Ressource ids are generated at apk build time and totally immutable.

Bottom line : if your Bitmap has to be pulled from somewhere later, you're stuck.
Corrolary: No notification icon are younger than their apk (up to gingerbread).

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use this code :

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
```

reference : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDrawables/article.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work because Notification as of api level 8 doesn't take a Drawable or a Bitmap, it takes a resource id (and only a resource id).